# How can someone in the lab synthesize n-allyl-4methyl-benzenesulfonamide from 4-toluenesulfonyl chloride and allylamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am trying to figoure out the conditions and choice of solvents and catalysts in order to run this synthesis.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself . Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange.

Comment: The name of your starting material - 4-toluenesulfonyl is incomplete. The question cannot be answered until you name your starting material correctly. Do you mean 4-toluenesulfonyl chloride?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward. 4-Toluenesulfonyl Chloride is readily attacked by nucleophiles and allylamine is a good nucleophile.

Dissolve 2.05 equivalents of allylamine (or 1.05 eq allylamine and 1 eq of an tertiary organic base such as triethylamine) in dichloromethane, cool in an ice/water bath (reaction is exothermic) then slowly add 1 eq of 4-toluenesulfonyl chloride dissolved in dichloromethane. Leave it half an hour then wash the reaction mixture with dil HCl soln, dried the organic phase, filter and concentrate to give your product.